# How to serve index.html for React and handle routing at the same paths?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, fastify

Using react you need to serve index.html with react_app.js included in it at any route if user have not downloaded react_app.js (came first time).

Then you need to serve some api calls from react_app.js, but if you use same url for GET, let's say, you will get API call response and not the index.html with react_app.js.

What is the solution for this? Make api calls only with some prefix and send index.html only if route not found?

My code:

```
fastify.register(require('fastify-static'), {
  root: path.join(__dirname, './static')
})

fastify.route({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/',
  handler: async (req, res) => {
    res.send('you will get api call answer but you need to serve index.html with react_app.js first!!!!')
  }
})
```

Comment: You can use the [Accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) header to switch between the index.html and the api calls, but most often I see api calls at a `/api/` prefix. It's easier that way, because sometimes setting the header is not as easy as just using a different route.

Answer (score 10):

As @Garrert suggested, this is how it will work:

```
// Статические файлы
fastify.register(require('fastify-static'), {
  root: path.join(__dirname, './static')
})

// this will work with fastify-static and send ./static/index.html
fastify.setNotFoundHandler((req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('index.html')
})

// Here go yours routes with prefix
fastify.register(async openRoutes => {
  openRoutes.register(require('./server/api/open'))
}, { prefix: '/api' })
```